# How to search for a series of integers in a text column in Python and Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a comma separated `string` in `Python` which I would like to compare to a `text` column in Postgres. The column looks like this:

```
data
{"ids":[id1]}
{"ids":[id2,id3,id4]}
{"ids":[id5,id6,id7]}
```

Comma separated `string` in python looks like this:

```
id1,id2,id3..
```

All the `ids` are `integer` values. I'd like to take all the `ids` in the comma separated `string` and match them with the `data` column in Postgres and return matching results. The Postgres table is very large, so I cannot download it in memory and perform string comparison. The `data` column is `text`.

I could easily match if I had only 1 `id` to match using the `like` operator. But I do not know how to match a bunch of comma separated values.

Expected resultset in the sample case is:

```
data
{"ids":[id1]}
{"ids":[id2,id3,id4]}
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: What will be the result of your sample case?

Comment: Updated the expected result in the question.

Comment: So "*match*" means that for each item in your string we found a record in DB that contains it. Did I get it rights?,

Comment: Correct. I can do this using the `similar to` operator as well. But that's taking a lot of time. So I'm wondering if there's a faster way?